# How can I check if a TextField contains unicode characters in flutter / dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to count the number of characters in a `TextField` for a messaging application. If the message body contains any `Unicode` characters, total length per message is 70 characters and 160 otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**string.codeUnits** is an array of Unicode UTF-16 code units.
So i would say it could be like

```
int maxLengthOfTextField(String text){
  final int maxBits = 128;
  List<int> unicodeSymbols = text.codeUnits.where((ch) => ch > maxBits ).toList();
  return unicodeSymbols.length > 0 ? 160 : 70;
}

final textFieldController = TextEditingController();
TextField(
  controller: textFieldController,
  maxLength: maxLengthOfTextField(textFieldController.text)
);
```